# How to to separate few Excel-Vsto-Ribbons to different Excel-Tabs after installing?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have 3 VSTO-Ribbons for Excel.
After installing each of them there is only one tab (with last installed Ribbon name) and there are 3 groups there for each of Ribbon.
How to to separate few Excel-Vsto-Ribbons to different Excel-Tabs with their onw Names after installing vsto-project ?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? IIRC, you can customize the ribbon (right click it) and you should be able to move them around from there, create new groups, etc.

Comment: this is in Excel after installing few Ribbons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you must separate the tabs at development time, by creating different ribbons tabs AND by giving different names to these tabs. Once installed there is no way to move controls between tabs.